# How does the /tellraw command work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I tried this:

```
/tellraw @a {"text":"","color":"blue","extra":[{"selector":@p[score_wins_min=1},{"text":" has won the game!"}]}
```

but Minecraft doesn't know the command and doesn't do anything. Why? I want to make a Bedwars server.

Comment: /tellraw requires a raw JSON message. Minecraft's wiki's have a combination of all the JSON syntax for a tellraw message: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Commands/tellraw

Comment: The JSON you posted misses a `]` after `score_wins_min=1`. It should be `/tellraw @a {"text":"","color":"blue","extra":[{"selector":@p[score_wins_min=1]},{"text":" has won the game!"}]}`. I'm not sure about the JSON content though, [here](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Raw_JSON_text_format) is another resource on that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what version you're playing on but this will work on 1.19.2 confirmed and most likely the recent previous versions as well.

I changed the command to work for you:

```
/tellraw @a [{"selector":"@p[scores={wins=1..}]","color":"yellow"},{"text":" has won the game!","color":"blue"}]
```

The command first selects a player that has a score `wins` of 1 or more in yellow, and then the text in blue.